# How to execute a function before an NSOperation is cancelled in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I want to execute a function before an NSOperation is cancelled. In `main` function, I add below code to achieve this goal:

```
if (self.isCancelled) {
    [self doSomething];
    return;
}
```

But if I cancel an operation before its start method is called, where should I call `doSomething`?

> For queued operations, it simply marks the operation as ready to
>   execute and lets the queue call its start method, which subsequently
>   exits and results in the clearing of the operation from the queue.

According to above Apple's document, I know that I can call `doSomething` in `start` function, so am I right?

```
- (void)start {
    if (self.isCancelled) {
        [self doSomething];
    }
    [super start];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the code you want to run in the completionblock.

Comment: But I don't want to call this function if the operation isn't cancelled

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm not familiar with NSOperation, since I can't use self. isCancelled in completionblock, so how to check it in completionblock?

Comment: You need to use a weak self.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223049/referencing-an-nsoperation-object-in-its-own-completion-block-with-arc