# self.navigationController pushViewController hangs on iPad 8.1

Tags: ios, ios8

While the following line works on iPhone 7.1/8.1, on iPad it only works on 7.1. On 8.1 the memory usage goes up and up until it crashes:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
```

This line happens here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    OBDialogDetailViewController* detailController = [[OBDialogDetailViewController alloc] initWithOption:(OBSelectionFilterOption*)option];
    [self animateChangeForView:nil atIndexPath:indexPath toRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) andNewHeight:0];
    if (self.navigationController)
    {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Since I just got responsible for this application, thas has grown over years and has no documentation, I'm a little bit desperate. I searched and tried multiple answeres and solutions for two days now.

Please tell me what more information I can provide.

[image]

Comment: If you comment out the call to animateChangeForView..., do you still have the problem?

Comment: Yep, still the same problem.

Comment: Do you see detailController? Is its viewDidLoad method called?

Comment: No, it seems as if not even the `- (void)loadView` is called.

Comment: Check if you can isolate the problem to `OBDialogDetailViewController` by replacing it with an ordinary `UIViewController`

Comment: Even i am facing with the same issue for iOS 8.1. Please update if you got the solution !

Comment: Look for answers that include how to use HeapShot (slightly renamed in the latest Xcode Instruments). Or look at the [blog entry](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) by bbum.

Answer (score 0):

It will not happen in all scenarios. But couple of things I would like to mention :

1. I was trying to play an encrypted video (heavy file) on the destination viewcontroller of UINavigationController. Method which decrypts and loads the video on that viewcontroller's view takes time when I load it in viewDidLoad. In that case, please use the following code.

   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createVideoPlayer) withObject:nil];
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(createVideoPlayerControllerView) withObject:nil];
2. Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10493470/how-to-exactly-find-where-memory-is-leaking-in-project-of-iphone) to manage memory issues even if you are using ARC.

This might not answer your question directly, but will certainly help you to debug. Please post whatever solution you get. Thanks.